# Linked lists in C example

Tags: c, linked-list

I'm having some problems with an example found on my textbook for using linked lists in C.

`startlist` is a linked list of `int` values and this piece of code should examine every `int` value and put it in `lowlist` if it is smaller than `X` or `highlist` if it is larger than `X`.

```
while(startList != NULL){
    if (startList->value < X){
        tempList = (List) malloc(sizeof(Item));
        tempList->value = startList->value;
        tempList->next = lowList; lowList = tempList;
    }
    else{
        tempList = (List) malloc(sizeof(Item));
        tempList->value = startList->value;
        tempList->next = highList; highList = tempList;
    }
    startList = startList->next;
}
```

I don't understand these lines:

```
        lowList = tempList;
```

and

```
        highList = tempList;
```

Why are they necessary?

Comment: `tempList` is a new node at first not connected anywhere, you set it's `next` pointer to point to the current first entry in the list, but then you need to make that newly created entry be the "official first list entry", hence `lowList = tempList;" or "highList = tempList;". (Without that you wouldn't be able to insert items into the lists.)

Comment: Not that the code you posted seems to leak memory. It creates copies of items in `startList`, but never `free`s the originals, just forgets them. But you should probably be *moving* items, so you should remove the `malloc`. You need 2 steps inside your loop: 1. take item from `startList`, 2. put that item to start of either `lowList` or `highList`.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, `lowList` and `highList` contain the lowest and highest nodes of the linked lists, respectively.

The lines

```
tempList->next = lowList;
```

and

```
tempList->next = highList;
```

set the next element of `tempList` to the lowest and highest element, respectively.

The lines you are talking about set `tempList` to the new lowest/highest node. `tempList` is now the first/last element, pointing to the old head/tail.

The whole loop is about prepending/appending new nodes in a sorted manner to the linked list.